# Build for archiving in Xcode 5

Tags: build, xcode5

Just upgrade to xcode 5 and i saw "Build for archiving" missing in product menu.
I go to Preferences/Key bindings and saw in product menu "build for -> installing", i put a key and it does not work.

So i execute this to do it :

xcodebuild -project *myproject*.xcodeproj -target *mytarget* -configuration Release

and i get the same thing as before in previous xcode with "build for archiving"
(Just build with release configuration)

Any idea how to "build for archiving" (not Product/archive) with xcode 5 GUI ?

Thank you

Answer (score 29):

" Note that if the Archive menu is disabled this is most likely because the a simulator option is currently selected as the run target in the Xcode toolbar. Changing this menu either to a connected device, or the generic iOS Device target option should enable the Archive option in Product menu. "

More info at http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Preparing_and_Submitting_an_iOS_7_Application_to_the_App_Store

Comment: 1 - It is not "Archive" menu but "Build for archiving" who disappear.( And not : disabled)

Comment: 2 - It is not for IOS with simulator but standard mac osx development.

Comment: Agree with Stephane, this is not the right answer. Context here is "Build for archiving" option, which was gone, and not the "Archive" option. Post by Victorb should be the right answer.

Answer (score 12):

It looks like they have combined the two steps "Build for Archiving" and "Archive" into one menu command: `Product -> Archive` in XCode 5.

Comment: Hoping that apple will not remove xcodebuild command from the next xcode release and asking for money for using it :).

Comment: I still can't find my .a library after archiving.

Comment: Yes, same thing with .app , i get a link pointing nowhere until i fill "Installation directory" (INSTALL_PATH) in build settings, i forgot that (too complicated for me :) ) and just run "cd my_project_dir" (where .xcodeproj is located) and  run xcodebuild -alltargets" and everthing is fine now.

Comment: No. Archive was always there, and it does something different and unrelated. Build for archiving  .... builds for archiving. Archive ... does not.

Comment: We don't talk about .xcarchive we talked about .a and .app who are no more built like it was before by using Build for archiving, because apple removed this option.

Comment: It looks like it does a build before Archiving, and that build must be in some output directory, right? If you find that output directory, then you effectively replace the missing Build for Archiving command.

Comment: Yes .app is put in directory "InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications" unfortunately **temporary** (just see that in log navigator).

Comment: This should be the right answer. @Stephane could rightly point this out by accepting this post as the answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can use "Build For Profiling", it is set to Release configuration.

Comment: Yes, twisting xcode is another solution.
So i have to set the configuration to release (because i change initially from release to Debug for instrument)
And unselect "Use the Run actions's arguments and environment variables" on Edit Scheme/Arguments for the profile scheme.

Comment: This is incorrect as Build for profiling could be debug or release set in the scheme.

Comment: By default it is set to release.